# Cast user-control to custom control type from type name?

Tags: c#, user-controls, casting

I am loading a *dynamically specified* user control into a place-holder in the parent (user) control like this:

```
// dynamically load instance of chosen chart control
string chartClassName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ChartControlClass"];
_chartControl = (IOutputChart)LoadControl(chartClassName + ".ascx");
// add to place-holder
if (chartClassName == "OutputChart_Dundas") phChart.Controls.Add((OutputChart_Dundas)_chartControl);
else if (chartClassName == "OutputChart_Microsoft") phChart.Controls.Add((OutputChart_Microsoft)_chartControl);
else if (chartClassName == "OutputChart_Telerik") phChart.Controls.Add((OutputChart_Telerik)_chartControl);
```

Clearly it would be nicer not to have to explicitly cast the `_chartControl` variable each time -- is there a cleaner way?  Each user control implements the `IOutputChart` interface; however, I can't use that directly because `Controls.Add()` expects a `Control` object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you not just convert all of these to `Control`?

```
phChart.Controls.Add((Control)_chartControl);
```

Comment: Ah -- well apparently yes, I can, so thanks for that <sheepish grin>.  I had tried casting to *WebControl*, thinking that this would work, but got the run-time error "Unable to cast object of type 'ASP.controls_outputchart_dundas_ascx' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl'." -- it didn't occur to me that "Control" would work whereas "WebControl" would not.  Thanks very much for the quickly, anyway -- much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I assume all of your controls derive from `Control` base class. Then why don't you cast the `_chartControl` to `Control` and add it.

```
_chartControl = (Control)LoadControl(chartClassName + ".ascx");
phChart.Controls.Add(_chartControl);
```

Comment: Indeed -- thanks very much (and see above comment for explanation of my apparent lack of effort first time around)!  I actually need the _chartControl variable as an IOutputChart object, though.

Comment: no problem. You can still use _chartControl as an IOutputChart object even the type of _chartControl is Control.